# как с помощью js создать n-нное количество блоков div?

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте нужно разместить в одном блоке div несколько других по определенному типу: картинка и текст снизу. ссылка на картинку и текст к ней берется из двух массивов. Нужно создать n-нное количество блоков div равное длине массива  imag с текстом и картинкой. Код сейчас такой:

```
var imag = document.getElementById('imag');
var text = document.getElementById('text');
img=[ 'картинка1','картинка2','картинка3','картинка4'];

textt=['текст1','текст2','текст3','текст4'];

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * img.length);

setTimeout( function() {
imag.src = (img[rand]+'.jpg');
text.innerHTML = textt[rand];
}, 1)
```

```
<div>
<img src="" alt="" id="imag">
<p id="text"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: _равное длине массива imag_ у Вас imag всегда будет 1 эл-том, о какой длине речь?

Comment: @InDevX очевидно о длине `img` и `textt`

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, ваш код совершенно не отвечает заданию. Он не создаёт несколько элементов, а один раз в миллисекунду меняет адрес изображения и текст уже готовых элементов, беря из по случайному индексу из массивов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (let i = 0; i < img.length; ++i) {
     let div = document.createElement("div");  
     
     let image = document.createElement("img");
     image.src = img[i];

     let p = document.createElement("p");
     p.innerHTML = textt[i];

     div.appendChild(image);
     div.appendChild(p);

     document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Думаю как-то так.